# PHP is concatenating instead of adding

Tags: php, concatenation

I'm having this problem where my PHP code is concatenating instead of adding

```
$offset=$_POST['offset']; //Get the offset
$searchLimit = 10;
$searchCount = count(sql) //For the purpose of this question, it returns the result count
```

Now I want to calculate the 'from' display for pagination, so I do

```
$from = ($offset*$searchLimit)+1;
```

It works fine when

> $offset == 0

I get the expected result which is 1. But when

> $offset == 1

It gives me 101. Basically it is concatenating the 10 and 1 to give me 101. I've tried the following

```
$from = (int)($offset*$searchLimit)+1
$from = ((int)($offset)*$searchLimit)+1
$from = (((int)($offset)*$searchLimit)+1)
```

I even tried

```
$offset = (int)$_POST['offset'];
```

But all of them are giving the same result.

Comment: Have you looked at PHP's `intval` function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: I have .. Actually tried it before writing this comment .. So this is what I tried ... `$from = (intval($offset*$searchLimit)+1)` but that doesn't help either ..

Comment: I would try `$offset = intval($_POST['offset']);` instead

Comment: How is `$from = ($offset*$searchLimit)+1;` 'working fine' if it returns `0` as stated? (0*10)+1 == 1 surely?

Comment: Sorry .. Once again that was my mistake in asking the question .. It is returning 1 which is the expected result .. I will correct the same in the question .. I will also try putting the intval around $_POST['offset'] .. I had initially tried `$offset = (int)$_POST['offset']` but that didn't do anything different ..

Comment: Sorry @RageD .. The `intval($_POST['offset'])` isn't helping either ..

Comment: @PrathameshDatar: I cannot reproduce your problem. Check here: http://ideone.com/cGID0n

Comment: @RageD .. Thanks for that .. I'll check what my PHP version is .. Don't know if that will help ... But I guess I learnt about a PHP testing place .. I will try and figure out the problem and post what the solution once found !! :D

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a `$` before `searchLimit`. As a result, it is being treated as a string. This result in unexpected behaviour.

Comment: A dollar sign might also be missing before `sql`. If you had enabled PHP's display_errors setting and set error_reporting to include E_NOTICE, you would have quickly discovered this problem.

Comment: Sorry .. The missing '$' is a typo .. I do have it in my code .. The sql line is just a pseudo-line. It is not the actual LOC in the application. It is the line that returns the count of the search result.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a $ sign before searchLimit (and perhaps before sql). -_-